# Create dynamic url from user input

Tags: javascript, android, url, dynamic

I am running a blog: http://jokesofindia.blogspot.com. I want to provide a dynamic link in the sidebar of my blog to download a Hindi newspaper in pdf format.

I tried to view source url of epaper.patrika.com and found that if I enter the url `epaper.patrika.com/pdf/get/145635/1` it will download the first page and `epaper.patrika.com/pdf/get/145635/2` it will download second page, and so on.

The last part of url is the page number. But the second to last part of the url, '145635', changes every day. Now I want   to be able to enter this changing part of url manually every day and then have the JavaScript  generate download links with the date replaced by the information I entered.

This code also needs to work on mobile devices such as Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html5 data object to store the data and use JS to get that data and append it to the link:

HTML

```
<div class="linkholder" data-number="12345">
    <a href="epaper.patrika.com/pdf/get/#/1">PDF page 1</a>
    <a href="epaper.patrika.com/pdf/get/#/2">PDF page 2</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var newNum = $('.linkholder').attr('data-number');
  $('.linkholder a').each(function() { 
    var newLink = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', newNum);
    $(this).attr('href',newLink);  
  });
});
```

view the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mtBcb) to see it in action.